# Omega theme in IE 9

Tags: 7, theming

I installed the "Omega" theme on my local server. Looks just what I needed! Responsive webdesign in just a few minutes.

When you take a look at the [Omega Micro-site](http://omega.developmentgeeks.com/), you will see that everything works great, also in IE9. But when I installed the template on my server it doesn't work in IE9... I always see the template with largest grid loaded.

Comment: It might sound really silly, but have you actually enabled the responsive grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your press F12 in IE9 to bring up the developer tools, what are Browser Mode and Document Mode set to? If they are not IE9, trying changing the settings to IE9 to see if responsiveness then works.

You might look at Tools->Compatibility View settings. See if "Display intranet sites in Compability View" is checked. Try unchecking this and refreshing.

Comment: Yes, that did it! But why is IE9 set to compatibility mode? If this is on every new installed IE9, then the responsiveness won't work in IE on every PC... Thanks for the correct answer!

Comment: It _is_ a nuisance. The check box is only for intranet sites; MS figured intranet apps were more likely to be broken. For more info, see the [MS doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567845%28VS.85%29.aspx) and many [stackoverflow questions on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie8-compatibility-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CSS aggregation switched on on your local server? IE has like 31 CSS file limits. [Still not fixed in IE9](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d/)

Comment: This shouldn't cause an issue in Drupal 7. In non-aggregation mode it uses `@import` statements to get around that problem, and in aggregation mode there should never be anywhere near 31 CSS files produced

Comment: When I was looking for a solution I did see this problem, but the problem isn't fixed after enabling CSS aggregation in Drupal...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is not working but if the page is wider than 940px + 20px as you would expect, than need to check your theme settings > grid settings and uncheck the wider/fluid/narrow if you need a fulltime fixed width.

Make sure your primary layout is normal.
The primary layout will be used in case you disable the "responsive grid" option as well as for older versions of Internet Explorer.